# How does one make a current time clock using raphael js

Tags: javascript, raphael

I have a code for a clock using raphael library. The problem I am encountering is that I cannot get it to display the current time. I have the hands moving appropriately but it will not display "current time". I am sure there are errors in this code. However I have found the code and I am using it as a basis for my clock. I started learning this last week so I am unsure how to actually do this and what the code should say.

Hence, how should I change this code to:

make the clock display current time on computer. I thought that the get time function and get seconds ect should do this automatically?

Code is as follow

The code is as follows.

```
window.onload = function(){

var canvas = Raphael("pane",0,0,500,500);

canvas.circle(200,150,100).attr("stroke-width",2);
canvas.circle(200,150,3).attr("fill","#000");

var angleplus = 360,rad = Math.PI / 180,
cx = 200,cy =150 ,r = 90,
startangle = -90,angle=30,x,y, endangle;

 for(i=1;i<13;i++)
 {

     endangle = startangle + angle ;

     x = cx + r  * Math.cos(endangle * rad);
     y = cy + r * Math.sin(endangle * rad);

     canvas.text(x,y,i+"");

      startangle = endangle;
 }

var hand = canvas.path("M200 70L200 150").attr("stroke-width",1);
var minute_hand = canvas.path("M200 100L200 150").attr("stroke-width",2);
var hour_hand = canvas.path("M200 110L200 150").attr("stroke-width",3);

var time = new Date();

angle = time.getSeconds() * 6;

minute_hand.rotate(6 * time.getMinutes(),200,150);

var hr = time.getHours();
if(hr>12)
hr = hr -11;

hour_hand.rotate(30 * hr,200,150);

var minute_angle= 6 + time.getMinutes()*6,hour_angle=0.5+   
      time.getMinutes()*30;
setInterval(function(){
                 angle = angle + 6;
                 if(angle>=360)
                 {
                     angle=0;

                minute_hand.rotate(minute_angle,200,150);
                 minute_angle = minute_angle + 6;

                  hour_hand.rotate(hour_angle,200,150);
                      hour_angle = hour_angle + 0.5;
                 }
                  if(minute_angle>=360)
                  {
                      minute_angle=0;

                  }

                 hand.rotate(6,200,150);

                 },1000);
```

Comment: I am not certain how this is radically different from your previous three questions on this exact topic.

Comment: I have taken the other question off, it happened to get answered too :) Now it is, I would say, a radically different question!

Comment: I tried this in jsfiddle, and it looks like a clock.  What is wrong with it is you wrote too much code :-)  and some of the angles and additions are not consistent.  Also check whether rotations are cumulative or incremental.  In order to write good code you need to know if a command for the hand to go to 90 degrees always put the hand at the same spot, say, 3 o'clock, or does the hand instead rotate in 90 degree steps from 12 to 3 to 6 to 9 to 12.   In the last case the new rotate command at each update should only rotate by the change.   I'll leave you to discover which of these you need.

Comment: Oh, the code posted is missing a final `}` to close the  `window.onload()` function, and generally needs to be edited for clarity and proper indentation.

Comment: Hey again! Thanks a lot, I will check this out. The code I posted here is simply a (badly done) copy and paste. I have edited and changed mine, so it works fine, looks like a decent clock and the second hand it now move 6 degrees a second. So I do not need to add any more code to make the time display as the current time?

Comment: saying that, the angles and additions are as they are here, but I did include the missing } :)

Comment: After a few minutes my copy of what you posted is doing strange things.  The initial clock is correct but updating is not correct.  See http://jsfiddle.net/2us4u3t6/1/

Comment: this one in jsfiddle seems to work fine. Should I use this instead and modify it? I am not posting my code and I may choose to use to for university coursework and do not want to get accused of copying from myself. But mine is pretty much the same, different size clock, different background image etc

Comment: ahh hang on is that my code on jsfiddle? Now giving me the wrong time. I will try and figure out how to change it,

Comment: Do you know how to get the time in text?  Basically, you need something similar to `<span id='timenow'></span>` in the html and a `document.getElementById('timenow').innerHTML=date.toString()` in the JS.

Comment: No, I didnt know that but I think that's what I am trying to find out (I asked something similar on a recent question).

Comment: Well, that should give you plenty to do.  Good luck.

Comment: Ha thanks. Just trying to time code out now, looks similar to what I was trying to do. I am unsure as to how I would change the clock hands skipping forward. I have changed some code to     minute_hand.rotate(6,200,200);
         minute_angle = minute_angle + 10;

       hour_hand.rotate(30,200,200);
        hour_angle = hour_angle + 0.5;
      }
       if(minute_angle>=360)
       {
        minute_angle=0;

       }

     hand.rotate(6,200,200);